# VAAPI on broxton GPU

Tags: vaapi

I'm trying to get vaapi acceleration working on Ubuntu 16.10 for the Celeron J3455. I installed the drivers but when I run vainfo i get this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

if I set the driver manually I get this result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
vainfo: intel_driver.c:100: intel_driver_init: Assertion `VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_DRI1) || VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_DRI2) || VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_CUSTOM)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

and with vainfo --display drm i get what i was expecting

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ vainfo --display drm
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Broxton - 1.7.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

How can I get hardware acceleration working?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Mmmmm. I'm [jealous](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10576/more-details-on-broxton-quad-core-ecc-up-to-18-eus-of-gen9)

Answer (score 1):

Same hardware (*J3455*) and OS (*Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop*) here. I spent several hours on that and finally fixed it, so I hope I can help you with that!

First I tried multiple kernels (4.8.0.32, 4.8.0.34, 4.9.2 and 4.9.0-drm-intel-next), then updated libva to 1.7.3 using [wsnipex's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wsnipex/+archive/ubuntu/vaapi) and mesa to 13.0.3 using [Padoka's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) and actually up to that point VAAPI still wasn't working (`DISPLAY=:0 vainfo` was failing with same error you pointed out). Therefore I'm not even sure if these steps were needed at all.

Then I noticed that in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, there is no sign of i965 driver being loaded.

What did the trick for me was to add the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "intel"
  Driver      "intel"
EndSection
```

After restarting the X server, I was finally able to read the correct output from `vainfo`.